# Она привязала собаку таким узлом, чтобы онa потом легко смоглa отвязаться.

Tags: синтаксис

*Она привязала собаку таким узлом, **чтобы онa потом легко смоглa отвязаться**.*

Подскажите пожалуйста: выделенное ПП целевое или образа действия с целевым оттенком?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это СПП с придаточным, имеющим двойное значение: определение + цель, указательное слово (коррелят) ТАКОЙ и союз ЧТОБЫ.

По виду коррелята (местоименное прилагательное) мы и определяем вид придаточного.

Comment: Вера, это аналогичное предложение верхнему получается: 
"Она постаралась лечь в постель так, чтобы он проснулся и ушел."?

Comment: Это СПП с придаточным, имеющим двойное значение: образа действия + цель, указательное слово (коррелят) ТАК и союз ЧТОБЫ. Варианты похожи, только в одном случае мы определяем существительное, а в другом глагол.

Comment: súper, поняла Вас, Вера! спасибо!!! : )